# Dunkin Donuts MUFFINS - are they kosher?

Tags: kashrut-kosher

Ok - everyone talks about donuts and whether they are kosher everywhere or not, etc. what about muffins? Those need some love too. All i want right now is a pumpkin muffin and the only nearby DD is not certified kosher. If i could go to this branch near my office for muffins (or donuts, of course) that would just be amazing. Come on people! I know this is super complicated but i wanna hear all of it.

Basically, I really want to know if one can enter any DD branch and consume a muffin. According to straight up kashrut ingredients.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya.                                       Mi Yodeya is for those who base their lives on Jewish law and tradition and anyone interested in learning more. 


If you have a question about...
Jewish law or practice (what to do or why)
Jewish philosophy
a Jewish text (explaining a passage)
history of Judaism
language used in Judaism
general knowledge (science, etc.) as it relates directly to Judaism
... (examples) then you've come to the right place.  It's not clear to me what question you are actually asking - could you clarify please?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/29630/are-dunkin-donuts-kosher-without-hechsher

Comment: I’m referring to muffins at Dunkin Donuts branches that are not certified kosher. You’re saying that those are permitted for those who eat pas paltar?

Comment: I'm still trying to understand -- are you asking whether products made (kosher) a central (external) location and shipped fully baked are kosher when sold at a store which also sells non kosher products (or lacks supervision) or whether local baking of a fixed and kosher mix can have things be bought from a store which is unsupervised? I just don't understand why the rules for muffins would be any different from those of donuts.

Comment: Well i know muffins are different than their donuts since some branches actually finish baking the donuts in-store. All muffins are made in the factory as far as i understand (correct me if I’m wrong). But yes, i want to know if it is allowed in practice to enter any Dunkin Donuts and consume a muffin

Comment: @shmob I've reopened it. It could probably benefit from you [edit]ing in whatever details you're aware of about the production process for DD muffins, in particular. Also, regarding whether you personally should consume the pumpkin muffins are your local DD, I strongly recommend that you consult [*your local* rabbi](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9146/why-is-it-necessary-to-ask-a-rabbi), regardless of what answers you might get here.

Comment: [This comment](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/29630/are-dunkin-donuts-kosher-without-hechsher#comment74303_29642) seems relevant